# People doesn't look or vote my answers

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, voting

I answered at least 5 questions but I didn't get any comment or vote.

Also, when I looked at their profiles, the *last seen* timestamp is very recent.

Why people doesn't look at my answers?

Comment: Voting is not a requirement, it is a privilege which is done at the discretion of the user.

Comment: FWIW, I just looked through some of your more recent posts and I noticed that some of those questions seem as though the OP's were just looking for an answer whereas some of the other questions you answered, you posted the answers a day (maybe more) later than other answerers (so another answer has already been accepted / voted).

Comment: For one reason why, when you answer a question that [asks how to do something that's really bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282061/trying-to-change-datacontext-of-main-window-from-usercontrol/53285159#53285159) even though your answer may be technically correct it's not going to get upvotes. It may, in fact, get downvotes. When someone asks you how to cut off their own head to cure their headache, you don't get upvotes for telling them there's a sale on chopsaws down at Home Depot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no guarantee any user will vote or comment on any post.

Users are free to express their opinions whenever they want, and whichever way they want.

If you are not getting any feedback either in the form of votes or comments in any of your answers, it may be that you were particularly unlucky in choosing to answer questions from *fire and forget* type of users. It's always better to pick *good* questions to answer, since it's more likely the users who posted those are invested in getting a good answer.

Users who post very poor questions often are mostly worried about getting a quick solution and are usually not concerned in providing useful feedback for the community.

It's also possible that you are providing answers that are just... *meh*. Neither bad enough to be downvoted, but not good enough to be considered really useful.

Also, if they are not clear enough users may have trouble knowing exactly *what* to comment, since asking for clarification may not seem 
promising.

But hey, at least you are not getting down-votes (apparently).

Comment: '*It's also possible that you are providing answers that are just... meh. Neither bad enough to be downvoted, but not good enough to be considered really useful.*' - Absolutely this. Many a times posting an answer is just not enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you're answering *good* questions then the feedback that the author provides is not terribly relevant.  If it's a good question, lots of other people will be finding it and some of them will be giving feedback.  Bad questions are very unlikely to attract attention from anyone else, and so there is no one but the author to give feedback.

If you focus on writing good answers to good questions you'll get lots of feedback from *the entire community*.  If you focus on answering bad questions you'll only ever have much of a chance of getting feedback from *one person*, who may or may not be interested in providing feedback.